# Where does Sanji get his endless supply of cigarettes from?

Tags: one-piece

In the *One Piece* anime, there are numerous occassions where the crew runs out of critical supplies such as food, water, etc. However, Sanji never seems to run out of cigarettes. Furthermore, he is never shown to buy one in the anime.

Comment: The same place they get food.  Its just easier to run out of food/water when they take up more space on the ship, spoil, and you have a higher consumption rate (aka Luffy plus 8 "normal" eaters). Otherwise there is no canon answer.

Comment: Well that maybe true however in cases like the Alabasta Arc where theylose all their baggage Sanji's Cigar supply seems unaffected. Well they take up less space it can be strange at times. Sanji comes ut of the water completely drenched andin the next scene he lights a cigarette. I mean are they water proof as well?

Comment: What if... he rolls his own?!

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ He doesn't. He carries a pack of cigarettes with him (seen on multiple occasions).

Comment: Sanji is the only person on the team who smokes so it would make sense that he never actually has a shortage of those. Then again if your caught up in the manga recall his actual last name which may in the future subsequently answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could give you a canon answer but after a lot of searching I was not able to find one. Sanji with his cigarette was just something that was established with his character. If there was a long period of time that he went without one it just wouldn't feel right to a viewer because they are used to the cigarettes. I believe the longest period of time that he went without one was on Punk Hazard and he was in Nami's body, he obviously had some bigger distractions at hand that kept him from his addiction. I will continue searching to try and find a canon answer if I am able to I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I guess this answer should have been a comment. Nevertheless thanks for the answer though I'll wait for a more canonical answer.

Comment: @TheRanger This answer doesn't need to be a comment, like I stated as of now there is no canonical answer and since it is a small detail your probably won't get one. Oda himself could answer it but until he does answers along the same lines as mine will be proposed to your question.